# I wanted to know, if I can beat the dealers hand in poker?

Tags: reading-hands

Dealers hand: Qs Qc 3d 6c 9s

1st hand: 4s 5c 6s Kd Ah

5th hand: 5d 6d Jh Kh Ac

2nd hand: 2c 9c Tc Kc Ad

6th hand: 2d 4c 8d 9h Qd

3rd hand: 4h 5h 7h 9d Jd

7th hand: 3s 6h Ts Qh Ks

4th hand: 3h 4d 7d Jc As

8th hand: 2s 3c 5s 8c Js

So Who won?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SE, but I think you are unlikely to receive an answer to such a question because the format is very hard to read and follow. If you want advice on that, try posting hand like QsQc3d6c9s and then the rest in the same format so that it would be possible to compare it, and I will be happy to answer :)

Comment: Can you check it, I made so changes ?

Comment: What game are you playing? is this video poker, 5 card draw, a table game?

Comment: It’s 5 card draw

Comment: Dealer's pair of queens look like the best hand to me.

Answer (score 2):

Nice edit, now it is much more clear and easier to compare :)

Unfortunately, you would lose all of these hands since the dealer has a pair of queens, and neither of your hands can beat that. If you are not sure about what beats what in poker, you can check [poker hand rankings here](https://www.mypokercoaching.com/texas-holdem-poker-hands-rankings/).